# R quantstrat: Is it possible to use quantstrat to create complex rules?

Tags: sequence, workflow, rules, quantstrat

I went over demos within quantstrat GitHub, also took a bootcamp course on how to use the package and read several posts and Q&As concerning signals and rules, however I am still failing to implement complex rules where thresholds are hit multiple times in a given sequence/chain in order to create my entry point.

By now I am pretty much convinced I yet don't understand the mechanics so I can stretch examples I went through to implement rules such as this:

[image]

Beforehand, my expectation is just to get a hint on how to build a cross-over or threshold rule that is 'aware' of its place in a workflow so I can expand it into more complex cases, such as the one in the image above.